# range using another cell value ex. sum(a1:a(b1)) where b1 is 300

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I want to copy a value that lives in cell b7, down n number of times which lives in cell b6. I want to autofill this in column G without having to manually drag and fill

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(G2:INDIRECT("G2:G",B6))=row(G2:indirect("G2:G",B6)),B7))
```

this seems to just copy it all the way down rather than copying it only 300 times.

Comment: you can always write a custom function that does just what you want

Comment: Is this formula really working? `G2:INDIRECT...` isn't a valid sytnax.

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet link including desired output as this will increase your chances of getting a very prompt answer.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(B7&SUBSTITUTE(ROW(INDIRECT("G2:G"&B6+1))^0, 1, )))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♥"&B7, B6), "♥"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
=arrayformula(if(transpose(split(REPT("1,",B6),","))=1,B7))
```

Reply to your title question:

```
=sum(A1:offset( A1, B1 - 1, 0))
```